# datagridview columns in VB.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, vb.net-2010

[image: check this image]

I have 7 tables of COA as shown in the picture attached. What I need is whenever opening balance goto - (negative), the type must automatically show CR sign and whenever that account goto positive +, it must change to DR automatically.

EDIT
from comments :

```
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS ******/ 
SELECT TOP 1000    
       [AccountID] ,
       [Account_Title] ,
       [opening_balance] ,
       [Account_group] ,
       [Group_subHead] ,
       [Accounts_categories] ,
       [type] 
 FROM [dbo_main].[dbo].[COA]
```

Comment: what is the query ?

Comment: You say you have 7 tables, but you only show 1. Can you please add more information so we can help you better

Comment: Could you please elaborate on where SQL comes into this? I think you may find you can do this in VB.net.

Comment: @Matt If its a rule in his system, then instead of doing this in several places in the client, you could do it easier as a calculated column in sql, or in a view. Much easier to maintain

Comment: is the `Type` column calculated or is it an actual column in your table in your database ? If so, then dont just show it here as it should be, but fix the value in your database so you dont have to write any code to show it as it should be

Comment: brothers, this data is from ms sql server and this is COA (chart of accounts) whenever user do a transection, it get affect in COA balance. the issue is whenever balance of any account goto negitive, the Type column of that specific account is not shwoing CR. It showing DR only which is Entered while making Chart of accounts. what is need is, whenever any account's balance goto (-) negative while doing entries, his Type must get change to CR instead of DR

Comment: Then I would either change the column `Type` to a calculated column, or write a `trigger` that updates the `Type`column

Comment: It would help if you show the table schema for this table

Comment: /****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT TOP 1000 [AccountID]
      ,[Account_Title]
      ,[opening_balance]
      ,[Account_group]
      ,[Group_subHead]
      ,[Accounts_categories]
      ,[type]
  FROM [dbo_main].[dbo].[COA]

Comment: how can i do trigger ?

Comment: Please dont add info in a comment, but edit your question and place the new info there.

Comment: I did it for you this time, but please put relevant data in your question, not in a comment

Answer (score 0):

you have several options on how to do this, which one suits you best only you can know

Note that all solutions assume that `AccountID` is the primary key of table `COA`, if that is not the case you will have to make adjustments

No doubt there will be more options, I just mentioned a few that come to mind.

**first option:** alter the query so it calculates the correct value for the column `Type`, and thus makes saving the value in the database no neccesary anymore

```
SELECT TOP 1000    
       [AccountID] ,
       [Account_Title] ,
       [opening_balance] ,
       [Account_group] ,
       [Group_subHead] ,
       [Accounts_categories] ,
       case when [opening_balance] < 0 then 'CR' else 'DR' end as Type
 FROM [dbo_main].[dbo].[COA]
```

**second option:** Alter the table schema of your table so that the column `Type` is a calculated column

```
alter table [dbo_main].[dbo].[COA] drop column type

alter table [dbo_main].[dbo].[COA] 
add Type as case when [opening_balance] < 0 then 'CR' else 'DR' end
```

**third option:** write a trigger that keeps the value the column `Type` correct

```
create trigger tr_UI_dbo_main on [dbo_main].[dbo].[COA]
for update, insert
as
begin
      set nocount on

      update [dbo_main].[dbo].[COA]
      set    type = 'CR'
      where  AccountID in (select AccountID from inserted)
      and    Opening_balance < 0

      update [dbo_main].[dbo].[COA]
      set    type = 'DR'
      where  AccountID in (select AccountID from inserted)
      and    Opening_balance >= 0
end
```

**fourth option:** Write code in your vb client that alters the text in the datagrid
Unfortunate I dont know VB, so you will have to look up how to do this yourself

**fifth option:** write a view and use that view in stead of querying the table direct. This also means there is no use anymore to store the value of Type in your table, just like the first option

```
create view vw_COA as
SELECT [AccountID] ,
       [Account_Title] ,
       [opening_balance] ,
       [Account_group] ,
       [Group_subHead] ,
       [Accounts_categories] ,
       case when [opening_balance] < 0 then 'CR' else 'DR' end as Type
 FROM [dbo_main].[dbo].[COA]
```

and use the view in your client like this

```
SELECT top 1000
       [AccountID] ,
       [Account_Title] ,
       [opening_balance] ,
       [Account_group] ,
       [Group_subHead] ,
       [Accounts_categories] ,
       Type
 FROM [dbo_main].[dbo].vw_COA
```

Comment: awesome bro your 1st option is working great on sql but can anyone help me to change it to vb.net i mean how can i use it in vb               SELECT TOP 1000    
       [AccountID] ,
       [Account_Title] ,
       [opening_balance] ,
       [Account_group] ,
       [Group_subHead] ,
       [Accounts_categories] ,
       case when [opening_balance] < 0 then 'CR' else 'DR' end as Type
 FROM [dbo_main].[dbo].[COA]

Comment: how did you used it before ?

Comment: i use it but it showing first 1000 records only. i do not want to limit it

Comment: then just leave out the `top 1000` part of the query

Comment: but will it keep update the COA/? i mean if i am doing cash payment entry and an account goes to negative so will it update in sql ?

Comment: if you use option 1 then no. It will only display the correct value. For that you need to use the 2nd or 3rth option

Comment: I dont know your complete situation, only you know that. If the column `Type` in table `COA` only needs to get updated if the `opening_balance` changes and nowhere else, I would recommend the second option. Drop that column and recreate it as a calculated column. But again, I dont know your situation, only you know that